# What is the reason behind getting none when I use print in the function and it is solved when you use return?

Tags: python

Here print function is used at the function greet.

```
def greet(first_name, last_name):
    name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    print(f"Hi {name.title()}")

friend = greet('ben', 'smith')
print(friend)
```

Here the output is:

> Hi Ben Smith
> None

But if the code if I use return in the last statement of function greet  then the problem is solved.

```
def greet(first_name, last_name):
    name = f"Hi {first_name} {last_name}"
    return name.title()

friend = greet('ben', 'smith')
print(friend)
```

Here output is:

> Hi Ben Smith

Comment: If the function doesn't return a value, it returns `None` by default. What do you expect it to assign to `friend` instead?

Comment: Returning and printing are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a `return` statement in the function then it is functionally equivalent to `return None`. i.e.

```
def foo():
    print("bar")
```

Is the same as writing:

```
def foo():
    print("bar")
    return None
```